# How to request Push Notification Permission for iOS with react-native-permissions?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-permissions

I'm using react-native-permissions library to request permissions in our react-native app.

Currently I'm implementing push notification. For Android I can request Push Notification Permission with native modal using `request(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)` . But for iOS I don't see a way to request push permission.

But

```
await checkNotifications()
  .then(({ status, settings }) => {
    console.log('CHECK STATUS: ', status);
    console.log('CHECK SETTINGS: ', settings);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log('CHECK ERROR: ', err));
```

works though it doesn't open the modal.
How can I request the push permission in iOS ?

Answer (score 1):

Found it.
It can be done with `RNPermissions.requestNotifications` method

Answer (score 0):

For **iOS** I use **requestNotifications** from **react-native-permissions** as follow:

```
import { requestNotifications } from "react-native-permissions";


  const requestNotificationPermissions = async () => {
    try {
      const { status, settings } = await requestNotifications([
        "alert",
        "badge",
        "sound",
      ]);
      console.log("Notification permissions status:", status);
      console.log("Notification settings:", settings);

      if (status === "granted") {
        // Permissions granted, you can proceed with your notification logic
        NotificationService.getToken();
      } else {
        // Permissions denied, handle accordingly (show a message, etc.)
        Alert.alert(
          "Permission Denied",
          "You need to enable notifications for this app."
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error requesting notification permissions:", error);
    }
  };
```

And call it on useEffect as follow:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    requestNotificationPermissions();
  }, []);
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: Don't forget to set NSUserNotificationsUsageDescription in ios/app_name/Info.plist:

```
<key>NSUserNotificationsUsageDescription</key>
<string>EXMPLE: Allow Notification to receive alert about important news!</string>
```

And add this to ios/app_name/PodFile

```
setup_permissions([
  'Notifications',
])
```

For **Android** it easy just use:

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from "react-native";
PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
    );
```

And add this in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```